# How to create responsive combobox in UWP?

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to build a repsonsive combobox, i.e.:

1. when the list of items didn't fit to the width of the parent => combobox with dropdown
2. when the list of items fit to the width of the parent => combobox without dropdown (like a listbox)

For the case number 2 I'm trying to modify the style of the combobox (minimal example):

```
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxFlatStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">


        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <CarouselPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>


                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <StackPanel>
                     <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">

                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <FontIcon x:Name="DropDownGlyph" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E5;" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,10,10,10" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        **<Popup x:Name="Popup">**
                        <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBackground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,-1,0,-1" >
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownForeground}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" MinWidth="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownContentMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                <ItemsPresenter Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

If I remove the popup element, the "SelectedItem" will not be triggerd (always null on tap-event), somehow the selectedItem is connected to the popup element. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: How did you know if the list of items fit to the width of the parent?

Comment: With my testing, I bind `SelectedItem` to my custom property and set the mode=TwoWay, when I select one item, the "SelectedItem" will be triggered. I could get the selectedItem's value in my ViewModel. So, could you please provide a [mcve]? Then, I could help you diagnose it on my side.